# Rails: Controller permitted params do not show up in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 5. I'm trying to make a simple search form, and then show the results in the index of the controller. Unfortunately, my "search_params" get lost between the controller and the view.

Search Partial

```
#_search.html.erb
<%= form_with( url: flights_path, method: "GET") do %>
  <%= select_tag(:from, options_for_select(@airport_codes) ) %>
  <%= select_tag(:to, options_for_select(@airport_codes)) %>
  <%= number_field_tag(:passenger_count, 2, in: 1..10) %>
  <%= select_tag(:date, options_for_select(@search_dates), include_blank: "(Any)", required: false ) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Console on submission:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "from"=>"YVR", "to"=>"YYC", "passenger_count"=>"2", "date"=>"", "commit"=>"Search"}
```

Controller:

```
#flights_controller.rb
class FlightsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @search = search_params
  @airport_codes = #list of airports
  @search_dates = #list of future dates
  @flight_results = Flight.search(search_params).includes(:to, :from)
end

def search_params
  params.permit(:from, :to, :passenger_count, :date)
end
end
```

But when I get to index.html.erb...

```
#index.html.erb
  <%= render "search" %>
  <%= @search %>
```

The @search line shows up as {} When I puts @search in the controller, everything looks fine in the console, but then it seems to disappear. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Alright folks. The problem lies in the line:

```
params.permit(:from, :to, :passenger_count, :date)
```

In order to get the data pushed through to the view, it needs to have a 'require' method in there like so:

```
params.require(:search).permit(:from, :to, :passenger_count, :date)
```

That means reconfiguring each tag line manually in the search form like so:

```
<%= label_tag( "search[from]", "Departing from:") %>
```

I must have been misusing the helpers. It would be great to know why 'require' is necessary.